# How to selectively substract a pair indexs from an array using python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of 10 elements, and I would like to compute the following

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and wish to do the following operation:

```
k = [a[1]-a[0], a[3]-a[2], a[5]-a[4], a[7]-a[6], a[9]-a[8]]
```

I wish to extend this operation any array size.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the length guaranteed to be even?

Comment: I had obtained the values of 'a' from calculating all the peak maxima from a time-series data. I tried the from scipy.sginal using peak_widths, tried to get the width of the peak maxima.

Comment: I am getting this time-series data from a sensor that I have been working. Therefore, I won't have any control over the length, sorry

Answer (score 1):

For a list with even elements you could build upon the following:

```py
a = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]

m = []
for i in range(1,len(a)-1):
    m.append([a[i] - a[i-1]])

print(m)
```